# SQL Server query runs - but no data is returned

Tags: sql-server, database, mssql-jdbc

Although the following query runs, no data is being returned. The query splits columns into `JudgmentMonth`, `Consumer` and `Commercial`. My knowledge of SQL Server is not great but I'm guessing no date parameters are given hence no data is being returned. I'm not sure where date is to be manually entered after >= and <=

```
WITH dset AS
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(category) AS Volumes, 
        MONTH(creation_date) AS JudgmentMonth, 
        transaction_type, 
        REPLACE(record_type, 3, 2) AS RecordType
    FROM 
        table 
    WHERE 
        transaction_type = 'jg' 
        AND category = 'CCJ' 
        AND CAST(creation_date AS DATE) >=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 101) 
        AND CAST(creation_date AS DATE) <=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 101)
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(creation_date), transaction_type, REPLACE(record_type, 3, 2)
)
SELECT    
    x.JudgmentMonth,
    MAX(CASE x.RecordType WHEN '1' THEN x.Volumes END) CONSUMER,
    MAX(CASE x.RecordType WHEN '2' THEN x.Volumes END) COMMERCIAL
FROM    
    (SELECT    
         r.JudgmentMonth, r.RecordType, r.Volumes
     FROM    
         dset r) x
GROUP BY 
    x.JudgmentMonth
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with Oracle?

Comment: Why are you converting your dates (GETDATE()) to varchar? That's not going to work. Just use convert(date, getdate()) instead? And if it's just one date, then use =

Comment: usually, comparing different data types doesnt make sense..

Answer (score 1):

You are giving it dates: you give it getdate() twice!

```
creation_date >= getdate and creation_date <= getdate
```

is the same as

```
creation_date = getdate()
```

So unless you have rows with a creation_date exactly matching the current date/time, you won't get much at all.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your column `creation_date` to a `date` is going to make your query non-SARGable. *Assuming* that what you want is data for tthe current date, I would suggest:

```
...
WHERE ...
  AND creation_date >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND creation_date < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY...
```

This will create a SARGable query, and thus perform far faster than converting both sides of the expression.